# mount Saga in react-native application

Tags: react-native, redux-saga

When I try to integrate saga in a react-native application I get the following error:

[image]

Here is the store file:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import placeReducer from './reducers/placeReducer';
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import { apiSaga } from "./sagas/api-saga";

const storeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const initialiseSagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  places: placeReducer
});

const configureStore = () => {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    storeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(initialiseSagaMiddleware)))
}

initialiseSagaMiddleware.run(apiSaga);

export default configureStore;
```

Thanks in advance

Kobi

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the enhancer

```
const configureStore = () => {
  return createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(initialiseSagaMiddleware))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass a default/initial state into the second param of `createStore`, then move your `initialiseSagaMiddleware.run(apiSaga);` to inside the function.

```
const configureStore = () => {
  return createStore(
  rootReducer,
  {},
  storeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(initialiseSagaMiddleware)));
  initialiseSagaMiddleware.run(apiSaga);
}
```